# pytest database access takes 66 seconds to start

Tags: user-interface, django-models, pytest, pytest-django

This is my `core/tests.py` that I use with `pytest-django`:

```py
import pytest

def test_no_db():
    pass

def test_with_db(db):
    pass
```

Seems that setting up to inject [db](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#std-fixture-db) takes 66 seconds. When the tests start, collection is almost instant, followed by a 66-second pause, then the tests run rapidly.

If I disable the second test, the entire test suite runs in 0.002 seconds.
The database runs on PostgreSQL.

I run my tests like this:

```sh
$ pytest -v --noconftest core/tests.py
================================================================================ test session starts ================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /home/mslinn/venv/aw/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
django: settings: main.settings.test (from ini)
rootdir: /var/work/ancientWarmth/ancientWarmth, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: timer-0.0.11, django-4.4.0, Faker-8.0.0
collected 2 items

core/tests.py::test_with_db PASSED                                                                                                                                            [50%]
core/tests.py::test_no_db PASSED                                                                                                                                              [100%]

=================================================================================== pytest-timer ====================================================================================
[success] 61.18% core/tests.py::test_with_db: 0.0003s
[success] 38.82% core/tests.py::test_no_db: 0.0002s
====================================================================== 2 passed, 0 skipped in 68.04s (0:01:08) ======================================================================
```

`pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = main.settings.test
FAIL_INVALID_TEMPLATE_VARS = True
filterwarnings = ignore::django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango40Warning
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Why does this happen? What can I do?

Comment: It will create a test database and thus has to perform all migration files to get the test db in the same state as your current models.

Comment: There are few migrations. This is really slow. I found these docs (https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#django-db-keepdb), but they confuse me, and it is unclear how to use the info: "django_db_keepdb: Returns whether or not to re-use an existing database and to keep it after the test run. The default implementation handles the --reuse-db and --create-db command line options. This fixture is by default requested from django_db_setup."

Comment: the *number* of migrations is not that important, the question is *what* migrations it will run